# Java's ByteBuffer compareTo: Comparing a byte to itself "For float and double"?

Tags: java

Inside of [Java's ByteBuffer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) is the method compareTo for implementing Comparable<ByteBuffer>...

```
public int compareTo(ByteBuffer that) {
    int n = this.position() + Math.min(this.remaining(), that.remaining());
    for (int i = this.position(), j = that.position(); i < n; i++, j++) {
        byte v1 = this.get(i);
        byte v2 = that.get(j);
        if (v1 == v2)
            continue;
        if ((v1 != v1) && (v2 != v2)) // For float and double
            continue;
        if (v1 < v2)
            return -1;
        return +1;
    }
    return this.remaining() - that.remaining();
}
```

What is the point of `if ((v1 != v1) && (v2 != v2)) // For float and double`?

If I write this kind of code, I'm warned about comparing identical expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Double.NaN == Double.NaN`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#NaN) and [`Float.NaN == Float.NaN`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#NaN) gives `false`.

See also end of [JLS 4.2.3](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/typesValues.doc.html#16083):

> The equality operator == returns false if either operand is NaN, and the inequality operator != returns true if either operand is NaN (§15.21.1).

Answer (score 2):

In that particular code, it doesn't make sense.  However, that's a popular idiom for floats and doubles.  Both can be "NaN", meaning they don't represent a valid, comparable number.  NaN is technically not equal to anything, even itself, so for a float or double that code would check to see if both are NaN, which is enough in this case to call them equal.

Comment: I get it; there's a Buffer for each primitive type, so this is how compareTo is implemented for FloatBuffer and DoubleBuffer. The code is probably mechanically-generated.

Answer (score 2):

I seems the Buffer classes are generated from a common source code template, this particular line only makes sense for the float and double versions to detect the special case where both numbers are NANs.

Comment: as a reference: public abstract FloatBuffer asFloatBuffer();

Answer (score 0):

As all the other anwsers already pointed out, it the check for `Float.NaN` and `Double.NaN`. They should have used `Float.isNan` and `Double.isNaN`.  This would have made that code way more readable. Long story short: **Don't** emulate.